# How to change Virtual Box mac OS Big Sur to a different screen resolution (size), including 1366x768?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, command-prompt, screen-resolution, macos-big-sur

Disclaimer-- I just got this working for me in my Virtual Box 6 Big Sur guest OS version 11.1... This question is for people who relate to the same problems I have and spent hours searching the internet to no avail. I hope that others who found different solutions, especially when the solutions I tried did not work, can share theirs. Maybe someone can also explain why what I did works.

Refer to the following [Similar Forum](https://superuser.com/questions/443445/how-can-i-get-virtualbox-to-run-at-1366x768), which did not work for me, first.

I do not know if **VMwareTools** (press X to doubt) and **Virtual Box Darwin Guest Additions** (this was actually specified for Mac OS X so I'm not sure) are necessary, but what I tried did not work before I downloaded them. So maybe download them if the commands to follow do not work.

These are the steps I did: <I have a Windows 10 host computer>

-- Power off your virtual mac OS.

-- Run the Command Prompt *as Administrator*.

-- cd to where your VirtualBox folder is located, I believe the default is in the C drive, but mine is put in E intentionally; so you would do that by directing to the folder as such:

`cd Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox`

-- Then you can use the code

```
VBoxManage setextradata "Whatever Your Machine Is Called– vmname, put in these quotes" "VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution" "1920x1080"
```

You should edit 1920x1080 to the resolution you need, and the name of your vm. I have also seen other tutorials instructing to use the above without putting *`VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution`* in quotes. Didn't work for me. After putting the code, open up your vm and hopefully reso is changed.

NOW, I've painfully tried to make this work with 1366x768, but it did NOT work (it goes to the default reso instead). It only worked for certain standard resolutions where 1366x768 is not a part of. I found [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#efividmode) after a while, and it is probably why it didn't work. It wasn't supported as a standard resolution. So, I found [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#customvesa) and created a custom mode through the following:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "vmname again" "CustomVideoMode1" "1366x768x32"
```

After doing so, I tried again, to put the first block of code:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "Whatever Your Machine Is Called– vmname, put in these quotes" "VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution" "1366x768"
```

It worked. I am assuming it has to do with creating your own standard resolution, and only then can you use that resolution? Anyone confirming would be nice. Forgive me if I'm completely off the mark, this is my first time using virtual box properly.

I just realized there is an answer my question option at the end.

Comment: Hey @user numbers, I hope you aren't lonely anymore. :)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem as you, but I was too lazy to look for a solution for it. Fortunately, you've already done some work for us and I'm sure those hours were well spent!

The answer is in the **manuals** (whenever well-documented), always.

#### Custom Resolution example for a 1366x768 screen:

Specs:

- Guest: Macos Catalina 10.15.5
- Host: Windows 10

Run both:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "macosx" "CustomVideoMode1" "1366x768x32"
VBoxManage setextradata "macosx" VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution "1366x768"
```

#### Explanations from source

Quoting [VirtualBox's manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual):

1. If you don't run any commands it will apply the [default](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#efividmode).

> *Reason*: The default resolution is 1024x768

2. Choose a resolution from this [list](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#efividmode) (which contains some VESA standards), and run the following command: `VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution HxV`

> *Reason*: Apart from the standard VESA resolutions, the Oracle VM VirtualBox VESA BIOS enables you to add up to 16 custom video modes which will be reported to the guest operating system.*****

3. If you try to use a resolution which is not listed, you have to configure a Custom VESA Resolution **first** by running: `VBoxManage setextradata VM-name "CustomVideoMode1" "HxVxD"` **then** proceeding to step 2.

> *Reason*:  Additional video modes can be configured for each VM using the extra data facility. The extra data key is called CustomVideoModex with x being a number from 1 to 16. Please note that modes will be read from 1 until either the following number is not defined or 16 is reached.******

***** Does not apply when using Windows guests with the Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions.

****** Additional commands should be supplied to Linux